# Connect parameter variables in expandable connector

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

Two models are connected via an (empty) expandable connector.
One of the two, makes a connection between the expandable connector and a `parameter` variable.

I didn't expect any issue. On the contrary, I had some issues:

- OpenModelica compiles Version 2, but not Version 1

  ```
  [bus_param_out]: Failed to instantiate equation connect(controlBus.num, numberPar);
  Translation Error: Error occurred while flattening model bus_param
  ```
- Dymola does not compile either Version 1 or Version 2

  ```
  Connect does not refer to connectors in connect(bus_in.controlBus.num, bus_in.num);
  ```

  but `bus_in.num` is a `Real` and Modelica Specifications says

  > All components in an expandable connector are seen as connector instances even if they are not declared as such [i.e. it is possible to connect to e.g. a Real variable].

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?
My final goal is to link a `parameter` variable to an expandable connector (e.g. inform different vehicle components about the number of battery cells, let's say) *without* the need of an additional redundant variable. Is this possible?

The test code is the following:

- *bus_param.mo*

  ```
  model bus_param
    bus_param_in bus_in;
    bus_param_out bus_out;
  equation
    connect(bus_in.controlBus, bus_out.controlBus);
  end bus_param_custom;
  ```
- *bus_param_in.mo*

  ```
  model bus_param_in
    Real num;
    bus controlBus;
  equation
    connect(controlBus.num, num);
  end bus_param_in;
  ```
- *bus_param_out.mo* - Version 1

  ```
  model bus_param_out
    parameter Real numberPar = 3.0;
    bus controlBus;
  equation
    connect(controlBus.num, numberPar);
  end bus_param_out;
  ```
- *bus_param_out.mo* - Version 2

  ```
  model bus_param_out
    parameter Real numberPar = 3.0;
    Real number;
    bus controlBus;
  equation
    number = numberPar;
    connect(controlBus.num, numberPar);
  end bus_param_out;
  ```
- *bus.mo*

  ```
  expandable connector bus
  end bus;
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

f.wue already showed how to write a parameter to the bus. 
This post additionally  explains how to read the value without increasing the variability (so it stays a parameter).

To make its usage easier, here is the complete code of a demo package to show how to read and write parameters on busses.
It works with Dymola 2019 FD01 in pedantic mode and OMEdit v1.13.2.

```
package ParmeterToBus
  expandable connector bus
  end bus;

  model bus_param_out
    parameter Real numberPar;
    Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant helper(k=numberPar);
    bus controlBus;

  equation 
    connect(controlBus.number, helper.y);
  end bus_param_out;

  model bus_param_in
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput buffer;
    bus controlBus;
    final parameter Real num(fixed=false);  // users should not modify it, hence its final
  initial equation 
    num = buffer;
  equation 
    connect(buffer, controlBus.number);
  end bus_param_in;

  model example
    bus_param_in bus_in;
    bus_param_out bus_out(numberPar=7);
  equation 
    connect(bus_in.controlBus, bus_out.controlBus);
  end example;
end ParmeterToBus;
```

Note that the implementation is far from being straightforward. 
Some tweaks are necessary along with helper classes to overcome the following restrictions:

1. Only connectors can be used in connect statements.
   So we need

   - an instance of an constant block to write the value
     (helper in the code above)
   - an instance of an RealOutput connector to read the value
     (buffer in the code above)
2. Models and blocks are not allowed to have the prefix parameter.
   Therefore wee need the constant block to write the value, we cannot use a RealOutput connector here.
3. For parameters usually an initial equation is automatically generated from its binding equation.
   To prevent this, we have to set (fixed=false). This allows us to assign the parameter in the initialization phase with the value of a variable of higher variability - in our case the buffer.

Comment: This concept is similar to what is presented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55458425/8649763, with similar caveats regarding handling by tools and how future-proof it is...

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput num
```

to declare a Real that can be used in a connect statement.

**EDIT:**
As far as i know, connecting a parameter to a connector is not possible. Dymola will yield the error:

> Connect does not refer to connectors in connect

The official way would be to use `Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant`, which is equivalent to `RealOutput`. You can directly use a parameter like this:

```
model bus_param_out
  parameter Real number = 3;
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant num_con(k=number);
  bus controlBus;
equation 
  connect(controlBus.num, num_con.y);
end bus_param_out;
```

When using expandable connectors and connect these connectors, you have to make sure to set `bus.num`only once. Everything else will result in an error.

Try connecting everything with the graphical interface, that will maybe clear things up.

You can use the expandable connector outside of connect like this:

```
model bus_param_out
  Real number_of_bus;
  parameter Real number = 3;
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant num_con(k=number);
  bus controlBus;
equation 
  connect(controlBus.num, num_con.y);
  number_of_bus = controlBus.num;
end bus_param_out;
```

But trying to declare `parameter Real number_of_bus` will result in the following error:

> The variability of the definition equation: number_of_bus =
>   controlBus.num; is higher than the declared variability of the
>   variables.

because the connector is time-variant and the parameter constant.

Comment: I get for the current frontend in OpenModelica: v1 and v2 succeed. For `-d=newInst` neither succeeds (`bus_in.num` is not a valid connector).  But also, connecting to a parameter as in `bus_param_out` will cause equation balance problems (it becomes an assertion and not an equation).

Comment: @f.wue: it works, but I don't see why it is required to make the variable a connector in order for the expandable connector to work. That is not what the specifications (I think) are saying.

@sjoelund.se are you saing that v1 and v2 _do_ work with OpenModelica without `newInst` and they _do not_ work when you enable `newInst`.
Anyway, I modified the question to make clear that I would like to know if I can connect to `parameter` variable directly.

Comment: I hope my edit makes my answer more complete. 
As i work with dymola, i dont know what `-d=newInst` is or does. 
Equation balance problems in the current layout occur, yes, but the question is how to connect a parameter to a connecter.

Comment: `-d=newInst` is the new flattening in OpenModelica, which checks more restrictions in the Modelica specification.